# Dumb question: what is $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question

Let $\{I_n\}$ be a collection of intervals on $\Bbb {R}$, whose length denoted by $I_n = |I_n|$

Then what is $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k (I_n + \alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is some real number?

The notation confuses me:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^k (I_n + \alpha) = \sum_{n = 1}^k I_n +  \sum_{n = 1}^k \alpha = \sum_{n = 1}^k I_n +  \alpha \sum_{n = 1}^k 1$$

**What is $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k 1$?**

Confusion 1: $n$ was an index, there is no index in the $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k 1$ term...

Confusion 2:$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k 1 = 1 + 1 +\cdots + 1 = k$? or does that sum term does nothing since it is not summing over something indexed by $n$?$

Comment: 1+1+1... for k many ones = k

Comment: @bof Am I adding up $k$  $1$s though?

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=1}^k(n+1-n)$?

Comment: @zahbaz Oh I see, but you still skipped a step. Let $J_n = 1$, then $\sum\limits_{n  =1}^k J_n = k$, no problem makes sense.

Comment: Ah.. I'm unsure what you mean by summing up intervals. I was just addressing that $\sum_{n=1}^k 1 = 1+ \sum_{n=2}^k 1  = 1 + 1+ \sum_{n=3}^k 1 = \underbrace{1 + 1 + \cdots + 1}_{k}=k$

Comment: @zahbaz Okay it is my computer science intuition that is messing me up. I view summing as loop, and in a program, writing $\sum\limits_n^k 1$ is performing empty loop over a variable defined as the constant $1$ inside of the loop. Of course that constant is not going to change.

Comment: @bof I get what you are saying, but this way of thinking is also bad (ignoring the $S = S+1$ part) because $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k (\cdot)$ requires some dependence on $n$ in the $(\cdot)$, whereas $S$ by itself does not have any dependence on $n$. Unless if we made $S$ an array and we are picking $n-th$ entry of the array just like the $n-th$ entry of the set $\{I_n\}$ each time we do the sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{k}1=k$ since it is just adding ones $k$ times. I suppose you could think of the $1$ in a terms of $n$ by saying  $\sum_{n=1}^{k}n^0=k$ (as long as you don't start with $n=0$, in which case you need to define $0^0$).

Comment: I really like this way of thinking about it, cause the notation $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k 1 $ by itself doesn't make much sense, we should have some dependence on $n$ in the $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^k ( \cdot)$ part

Comment: @MSEisadatingsite No, we shouldn't really. In general there's no need for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you translate an interval by $\alpha$, it's length stays the same. Suppose $I=[3,4]$ and $\alpha=5$, $I+\alpha=[8,9]\implies |I+\alpha|=9-8=1=|I|$. Note that $|I+\alpha|\neq |I|+\alpha$.
So
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k |I_n+\alpha|=\sum_{n=1}^k|I_n|=\sum_{n=1}^k|I_1|=|I_1|\sum_{n=1}^k1=k|I
_1|
$$

Comment: Thanks you have identified a huge mistake in my assumption

Answer (score 1):

You can't "sum intervals". I believe that $I_k+\alpha$ means, if $I_k=(a_k,b_k)$, the interval $(a_k+\alpha, b_k+\alpha)$

Comment: Sorry I went lazy and overloaded the $I_k$ to be equal to the length, heh.

Comment: Ok... For your question, the sum is k

Comment: @MSEisadatingsite There is something called Minkowski addition of sets. In the special case for intervals you will have $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$.